# One Service reference across multiproject solution

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, projects-and-solutions

I would like to know how configure C# solution in VS2012 for more projects, and service reference only at one place.

I have three projects:

- A: MVC4 Web Application
- B: Class Library
- C: WCF Class Library service reference to a WCF service somewhere on the internet.

Setup:

- A has reference on B and C.
- B has reference on C
- C has not reference on project

In B I would like to call service method, from service reference, in C.

But always when I try it, I get `NullReferenceException`.

What is the right way for have only one service reference for the whole solution?

Comment: Are you trying to debug an exception or are you asking for guidance architecting your solution? Either way, you need to add detail and code samples to your question.

Comment: You can't have a solution-wide service reference.  Each assembly in the solution that will be using that service needs its own reference.